# Regular Expressions tool for Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, regex

Is there a regular expressions tool for Linux to ease the creation of big regular expressions, such as [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for instance, for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You might try [`txt2regex`](http://aurelio.net/soft/txt2regex/). It isn't as advanced as Expresso, but it's a Bash script, believe it or not. It's available in the Ubuntu repositories and may be in the ones for other distributions.

Answer (score 0):

One such tool is [Visual Regexp](http://laurent.riesterer.free.fr/regexp/) ([Ubuntu install link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/visual-regexp)).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an online tool. This would work on any platform.
I often use this one to create/test big regexes: [regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html).
It supports several syntaxes, including Perl, Java, Python, ...